# Programmatically get the number of indexed pages in Google?

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, google-chrome

As an SEO metric I'd like to programmatically get the number of by Google indexed pages.

(if I search "site:mydomain.com" I want the get number of pages found).

Is there any lib for this or do I need to parse a google request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use Google Webmaster Tool API.
First login in google webmaster with gmail account and familiar with the functionality then see following developer guide:
http://code.google.com/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I put together that will work for a few queries per IP address per hour:

```
    public static Int32 GooglePages(string sourceDomain)
    {
        String googleSource
            = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(
                @"http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A" + sourceDomain);

        return Convert.ToInt32(
            Regex.Match(googleSource, 
                @"about \<b\>([0-9,]*)\<\/b\> from ")
                .Groups[1].Value.Replace(",", ""));

    }
```

If you are going to use it often, or make many queries on a regular basis I would recommend using an officially sanctioned API.

Answer (score 2):

Has your site been setup in Google Analytics? If so you can use the [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/) to get such information.

If you're interested in how to implement this in asp.net [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791125/google-analytics-api-and-net).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a [Google API](http://code.google.com/more/) you can use, rather than parsing the results of a search.