# C# - get number of a website indexed page in google?

Tags: indexed

I wanted to know if there is a way to get number of pages of a website that indexed in Google. with ASP.net , C#
I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833926/programmatically-get-the-number-of-indexed-pages-in-google), but I didn't get it!
I don't know how to use Google API or even where can I get it!!
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use this library:
http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/