# Show Google Analytics dashboard on my site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, google-analytics, analytics

I have an ASP.NET website set up, and I'm using Google Analytics for page tracking. The only thing I don't like is that I have to go away from my site (to the Google Analytics site) to see the report.

Is there any way to show the Google Analytics data on my own site with all the AJAX that they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, GoogleAnalytics doesn't have an API that supports this yet. It's something many would love, and hopefully will be available in the future. For now, just open a tab and refresh occassionally.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use an iframe that's inside a `LoginView` that only administrators can see.  It won't circumvent authentication but you could at least proxy the analytics pages you cared about once you were authenticated.

Authenticating into analytics is pretty much a non-issue - at least for me.  I'm so often logged in to Google that I almost never have to do so.

Also the first link on the "related" sidebar looks... well... related:
[Google Analytics API and .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791125/google-analytics-api-and-net)

Answer (score 1):

As most of the stats are available in CSV and XML format downloads, why not use them as input for the new ASP.NET chart controls?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytic Dashboard Controls](http://gadashboardcontrols.codeplex.com/) does exactly this. The project is immature and not that full featured, but useful for a quick overview.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be doing a side product which does exactly this:
[www.embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty easy solution I made that's open source: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalytics.GoogleCharts.NET/

This pulls Google Analytics data and displays it on your page with Google Charts.

If you have any questions let me know.