# Show Google Analytics dashboard on my site

Tags: php, jquery, extjs

I have a PHP web site, i want to show google analytics on my admin section. I wish to use Jquery or extjs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Google Analytics dashboard on my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490137/show-google-analytics-dashboard-on-my-site)

Answer (score 12):

The first thing you've to know is that this is not possible. You need to use the GA API to get the data and then render it:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/

**More**:
Here you have a library in PHP to access easily to your GA data: http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Comment: What makes it not possible? From what I understand of your answer, you're describing a way to do it.

Comment: It's not possible to get jQuery and with a simple function print all the information. You can't show the panel. You've to build a panel like GA with the information you got from it. More clear?

Comment: @user326096: now, accept the answer and accept the other answers! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I do something similar using a 3rd party application called [Reporting Suite](http://www.reportingsuite.com) and it works perfectly for me. I get my metrics in a image that is published in our admin application.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed Google Analytics to your webpage using **Analytics Embed API**, here's a link to the guide by Google.

[Embed API Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/)

Using the sample code on the website will help you create a **Access Google Analytics** button on your page, logging in with which your dashboard is embedded to your webpage.

Comment: Add more details on the API.

Comment: great! You've made your post better. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to make your answer even better.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a 3rd party service check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  No programming necessary.  It uses the Google Analytics API.  All you do is define your chart and embed a snippet of code embedded in an iframe tag.

(disclosure: this is a service I have developed).

Answer (score 0):

the api have change and now, this is the documentation for that. 
[Google Analytics api embed charts own panel](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/)